# How to get sqlserver database name from datasource name in Java

Tags: java, database, sqldatasource

As specified in the title, I want to get the database name in sqlserver, all info I know is datasource name, login name/password to get the Connection object, please show some pointers on how to retrieve the database name correctly, in java, thanks!

Even

Comment: What do you mean by database name? Are you referring to the MS-SQL Server instance name or some other name?

Comment: I meant database instance name, as shown below:Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 06.00.6002

Data Source Name: SM9
Data Source Description: 
Server: ***
Database: SM9
Data Encryption: No

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtain an instance of `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` from the connection object.

The names of database can be obtained via `getCatalogs()` or `getSchemas()` method (It depends upon the vendor of JDBC driver).

```
ResultSet rs=cn.getMetaData().getSchemas();
while(rs.next()) {
   System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Or use `Connection.getCatalog()` or `Connection.getSchema()` method.

In case if you are interested to get `host name` or `ip address` of the Oracle database server.

```
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_NAME from dual");
 while(rs.next())
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<String> getServerDataBaseNameList() {
    List<String> dataBaseNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = con.getConnectionMetaData().getCatalogs();
        if (resultSet == null) {
            return null;
        }
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            dataBaseNameList.add(resultSet.getString(1));
        }
        return dataBaseNameList;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Error during execute select query for fetch server database name");
    }
    return null;
}
```