# How can I get sql server database name from DatabaseMetaData object

Tags: java, database, sqldatasource

I am wondering how can I get the database instance name from DatabaseMetaData, or is there any way I can do that, kind of stuck here, thanks for any pointers!

[How to get sqlserver database name from datasource name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116517/how-to-get-sqlserver-database-name-from-datasource-name-in-java)

Even

Comment: Could you please clearify what you would like to achieve? It is a little unclear to me what you mean by "database instance". I assume you've got the DatabaseMetaData via the Connection, which represents a connection to the database. You can do all the manipulation you'd like on the database via the Connection instance. However, it is unclear to me what you would like to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get sqlserver database name from datasource name in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116517/how-to-get-sqlserver-database-name-from-datasource-name-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've obtained a database connection:

```
// url is usually in the format jdbc:mysql://<ip address>:<port>/<database name>    
String url = theConnection..getMetaData().getURL();
String databaseName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(url, "/");
```

The above code uses StringUtils in Apache Commons Lang 3