# Can we create a Connection Object in Java without actually establishing a Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-string, mssql-jdbc

I understand that `Connection` is an interface and what are all the basic ways to get the Connection using `DriverManager` ? But what it does, it creates and opens a connection and returns it. So, is there a way to create a Connection or any similar object in Java which can give the metadata, dbName etc properties from a connection String?

Comment: Why don't you parse directly the connection string? Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11733697/2508770

Comment: @Emax He is talking about database connections; not URLs?!

Comment: Use [mockito](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-mock-database-connection-example) to mock DB connection

Comment: @GhostCat "or any similar object in java which can give me the metadata, dbName etc properties from a connection String", the connection string is an url so what's the problem of parsing it?

Comment: Plese refer to get the db details using connection object.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116517/how-to-get-sqlserver-database-name-from-datasource-name-in-java

Comment: @Emax a JDBC URL is an opaque object, the JDBC specification requires nothing more than `jdbc:<vendor>:<vendor-specific-part>`, everything after `jdbc:<vendor>:` is free to a specific driver implementation, and although it may look like a lot of drivers follow the same conventions, they do not all do that, and there are always subtle differences.

Comment: To get the connection details from a connection object, i will have to establish a connection first. Right now I am parsing the connection string itself using substring etc but if in future there is a change in connection string, i will have to change my code as well. Hence I was looking for something like MSSqlConnectionString object

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you, I wasn't understanding the question

Comment: Why are you parsing a connection string at all, it is - IMHO - the wrong way to go about things. If you need to manage this in some way, it would be better to use a driver-specific `DataSource` instead as it usually exposes all available properties as a collection of getters and setters.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  
Even to get the Data Source I will have to connect to the database first. I have a connection String But, there are certain places where I need the dbName. Its a legacy code hence we wanna implement new changes with minimum interference in the existing code

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible to obtain a `Connection` without connecting (unless you stubbed the interface yourself).

It sounds like your database name is hardcoded somewhere in the existing code. If so, perhaps you could extract it to a constant that could be referenced by your new code too. Then you'll have the database name directly as a `String` instead of indirectly via the `Connection` object. If the database name is embedded inside a connection URL, you might have to separate it out and construct the URL. E.g.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=" + DATABASE_NAME;
```

Even better would be to store the connection details separately from the code—e.g. in a properties file that is read when you program starts up—though that would require slightly more change to the existing code.